# Python Tkinter Button not appearing with grid

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to program a little calculator in python3 with Tkinter. When I try to organize my buttons and the input filed with grid(), my buttons are not appearing. I am sure I forgot something but hopefully someone can find my issue.

```
from tkinter import *

gleichung = ""

def zahl_gedrückt(num):
    global gleichung
    gleichung = gleichung + str(num)
    gleichung_text.set(gleichung)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Tk()
    app.title("Taschenrechner")
    app.geometry("400x600")

    gleichung_text = StringVar()
    gleichung_text.set('Gleichung...')
    gleichung_textbox = Entry(app, font=("Calibri 25"), state='disabled', width=400, justify='center', textvariable=gleichung_text)
    gleichung_textbox.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

    button1 = Button(app, text=' 1 ', font=("Calibri 40"), command=lambda: zahl_gedrückt(1)).grid(row=2, column=0)
    button2 = Button(app, text=' 2 ', font=("Calibri 40"), command=lambda: zahl_gedrückt(2)).grid(row=2, column=1)

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try resizing the window. The buttons are off-screen because you've made your entry widgets 400 _characters_ wide.

Comment: @BryanOakley how can I fix this?

Comment: remove `width=400` from your Entry call